# onReceive not being triggered in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

When I'm handling the case when a user denies the notifications, the onReceive block isn't being triggered. It's working if the user accepts the prompt for notifications. Any help would be appreciated. Here are the necessary snippets of code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UIView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LogInViewModel()
    ...
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            Button(action: {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [ .alert, .badge, .sound ]) { (success, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if success {
                                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                                } else {
                                    self.loginViewModel.loginCall(...)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }) {
                ...
            }.onReceive(loginViewModel.success) {
                print("Login successful!") // <- This doesn't get called if a user doesn't allow the notifications
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}

import Combine

class LogInViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var success = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    ...
    func loginCall(...) {
        async API call here { (result: Result<..., ...>) in
            if case .success(...) = result {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.success.send()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works with Xcode 11.2.1 / iOS 13.2.2

Comment: @SecretBit Have you find any solution?

Comment: Do you found the solution??